# how to toggle html form with toggle functon in pure javascript

Tags: javascript, html, toggle

I'm trying to toggle a complete html form `newBill` with pure java script by passing an `Id` of the form as an argument in JS function `toggle`and toggling with `onclick` event, but not sure why its not working at all.

```js
function toggle(id) {
  var e = document.getElementById(id);
  if (e.style.display == 'block' || e.style.display == '') {
    e.style.display = 'none';
  } else {
    e.style.display = 'block';
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="menu">
  <li><a href="#home" onclick="toggle(" newBill ")"> New Bill</a>
  </li>
</ul>
<form name="billnew" id="newBill">
  Order ID :
  <br>
  <input class="textBox" type="text" name="billid" id="order_id" />
  <!--More form fields below.-->
</form>
```

Comment: what error it is giving ?

Comment: You can't use double quotes inside text that is delimited by double quotes. You need `onclick="toggle('newBill')"` Or mask them: `onclick="toggle(\"newBill\")"` No go ahead and delete the question.

Comment: It does nothing on click of New Bill button

Comment: And check the browser console next time.

Comment: its working fine https://jsfiddle.net/uz0tebLr/

Answer (score 1):

perhaps on basis of your code I guess you need a single quote here

> toggle("newBill") its wrong

you need this

```
<a href="#home" onclick="toggle('newBill')"> New Bill</a>
```

Comment: yea..that's a typo error, but i am calling a new function inside the form which is not working there in, after toggle

Comment: where is your submit function call. it is not either on id or in html input type submit

Comment: @Prasad_Joshi Your question was about toggle hide/show not working, which was solved by correcting the typo, please open a new question for any other issues you are having and accept an answer on this question that solved your hide/show toggle problem.

Comment: Ok..thanks for the updates..will open a new question.

Answer (score 1):

change your onclick attribute

It should be like

```
onclick="toggle('newBill')"
```

Working example https://jsfiddle.net/uz0tebLr/